# If $E$ and $F$ are subfields of a finite field $K$ and $E$ is isomorphic to $F$, prove that $E=F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory

> If $E$ and $F$ are subfields of a finite field $K$ and $E$ is isomorphic to $F$, prove that $E=F$.

I know this question has been asked, but I have a different approach of proving the problem and I want to see if it works.

So if two finite fields are isomorphic, their cardinality is the same. And also all finite fields have order $p^n$ for some prime $p$. Now we consider the multiplicative group of $E$ and $F$ without $0$. The multiplicative group of $E$ and $F$ have $p^n-1$ elements and they both satisfy the equation $x^{p^{n}-1}-1=0$ where $x \in K$. Since this is true for both $E$ and $F$, they are in fact equal.

Now my question is, how do I show that there are no elements outside of $E$ or $F$ that satisfies $x^{p^{n}-1}-1=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^{p^n-1}-1$ has at most $p^n-1$ roots in $K$, and you have just as many in each of the subfields. By the way, you can avoid the ordeal of removing and adding back $0$ by saying that each subfield is a set of roots of $x^{p^n}-x$ instead.